# Can I reverse the sign on some of my PCA factor scores and how can I justify this?

Tags: pca, factor-analysis

I have conducted a PCA to reduce the dimensionality of kinematic performance. This has produced eight components. I now want to plot the trajectory across different age groups. For five of the tasks, the trajectory is as expected, however for three of these, the direction of the relationship is completely opposite. I have read that the sign is arbitrary but how can I justify inversing the sign of some scores but not others?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sign of what, the eigenvalue or the eigenvector?

Comment: The actual derived factor scores @Dave